# Defining Extra Variable Causes Error In Python

Tags: python

I have this code snippet: (I think that other parts of the code are not important. )

```
mol = editable_mol.GetMol()
neighbors = mol.GetAtomWithIdx(lastAtomIndex).GetNeighbors()
for nb_atom in neighbors:
    atom_type, h_aro, h_alp, h_beta, h_gam = common.getAtomTypeAndHmnr(nb_atom)
    if atom_type == 9:
        common.setAtomTypeAndHmnr(nb_atom, 9, 0, 1, 0, 0)
        Chem.EditableMol.ReplaceAtom(editable_mol, nb_atom.GetIdx(), nb_atom)
```

It runs perfectly. But if I use `editable_mol.GetMol()` instead of `mol` variable like this:

```
neighbors = editable_mol.GetMol().GetAtomWithIdx(lastAtomIndex).GetNeighbors()
for nb_atom in neighbors:
    atom_type, h_aro, h_alp, h_beta, h_gam = common.getAtomTypeAndHmnr(nb_atom)
    if atom_type == 9:
        common.setAtomTypeAndHmnr(nb_atom, 9, 0, 1, 0, 0)
        Chem.EditableMol.ReplaceAtom(editable_mol, nb_atom.GetIdx(), nb_atom)
```

The program gives an error. It means that I must use mol variable. But I do not understand why I must use it. Is it changes defining the extra variable in python? I think that both codes are the same.

Program gives this error but I think that this error is not related to content:

> atom_type, h_aro, h_alp, h_beta, h_gam =
>   common.getAtomTypeAndHmnr(nb_atom) 
>   File "C:\Users\phitech_halil\Documents\Tupras
>   Projects\MolGenPython\phitech\common.py", line 302, in
>   getAtomTypeAndHmnr return int(atom.GetProp(KEY_ATOM_TYPE)),
>   int(atom.GetProp(KEY_H_AROMATIC)), int(atom.GetProp(KEY_H_ALPHA)), \
>   KeyError: 'atom_type'

Only different is defining `mol` variable but the program gives an error. I think that problem cannot be related to `editable_mol` object or `GetMol()` function. Is there any idea?

Comment: Ok, so step by step, as I guess You are using `rdkit`, don't You ? So this python library is just an wrapper around C++. I have seen that some of classes in this kit are uisng `weakrefs` so maybe the problem is that this Mol object is collected by python garbage collector ?

Comment: I used rdkit. And yes it is wrapper of C++. I researched weakrefs and maybe it can be caused this problem. I did not know weakrefs. Thank you for enlightening me.